# Fit fixed size items inside a fixed size parent and leave out items that do not fit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, jquery-isotope

I have a fixed size container and a list of items with a fixed size (each item can have a different fixed size). I need to be able to fit a maximum amount of items inside the fixed size container and leave out those that do not fit.

This is what I have so far:

[image]

I have tried using [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co), which sort-of kind-of does the job when it comes to using as much space as possible, but it fits **everything** in it, changing the container size, which is not the desired end result.

#### In an ideal world

I would like to know how to get a list of items in a array that do not fit, so I could remove them from the container by looping over that array and also show items that did not fit below the container itself. All help is appreciated.

#### So far I have tried the following:

**Remove items that start clipping the container**

```
$('.grillitem', '.grill').filter(function() {
   return $('.grillitem').offset().top + $('.grillitem').height() < $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
}).hide();
```

This however does not work if items are `inline-block` or `block`, but `float:left;`. Which means I will not be able to use this in a way that I could maximize space usage.

**Using Isotope to maximize space usage**

```
var grid = document.querySelector('.grill');
var iso = new Isotope( grid, {
  // options...
  itemSelector: '.grillitem',
  percentPosition: true,
  masonry: {
    // set to the element
    columnWidth: '.grillitem'
  }
});
```

This does, sort-of maximize the space usage. However it does not respect the container height and overwrites that (even when I set the `!important` flag in CSS for container height) and I found no way to exclude items that do not fit in its documentation. I was hoping to combine the two ways of doing things above, but my way of excluding items that do not fit does not work with items that are `position:absolute`, which Isotope makes them be.

In other words, I'm completely lost.

Comment: please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please publish your code inside blocks

Comment: Added things I've tried so far.